# Why is it that Javascript treat values as an integer when subtracting but not addition?

Tags: javascript

I have two input fields that allow a user to enter 2 numbers with IDs, **x** and **y** respectively and a button to calculate the numbers. So when I try to add them up using `getElementById()` method, it treats the value as a **string** and just combines them together. I do know that I need to use `parseInt()` function to convert the string to an integer.

However, that is not the case when I use the **exact** same method for my subtraction function. It treats the value just like an integer. Does anyone have any idea why?

```js
function addition() {
    var number1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
 
    var total2 = number1 + number2;
    document.getElementById("tes4t").innerHTML = total2;
}


function subtract() {
    var number1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
    var number2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
 
    var total = number1 - number2;
    document.getElementById("tes4t").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
Number1 : <input type="number" id="num1">
<br>

Number 2:    <input type="number" id="num2">
<br>
<button onclick="addition()">add </button>
<button onclick="subtract()">subtract </button>




<div id="tes4t">

</div>
```

Comment: because "+" is also string concatenation operator. and getElementById("num1").value returns string.

Comment: Subtracting strings means nothing. Adding strings - concatenating - does.

Comment: Ah... i see thanks for the prompt respond!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Javascript `+` operator is also String operator that is used for `String` concatenation (e.g. "x" + "y" = "xy").

*Using `+` operator on two operands where at least one is a `String` engine will treat both operands as a `String` and perform concatenation.*

Since `getElementById("num1").value` returns `String`, using `+` will produce concatenated string.

In case of `-` as it is only Arithmetic operator - engine will try to convert operands' values to Number before applying the operator.

---

If you need to make sure that addition is performed you can use either `Number()` or `parseInt()` method to convert string value.

Answer (score 2):

It happens because "adding" two string values, you're actually concatenating this values.

An option is use the unary operator + to convert them to numbers or cast your variables

```
var total2 = +number1 + +number2;
```

Answer (score 2):

Javascript will try its very best to execute anything you write regardless of whether there is an incorrect input or value use. If it can use it as another type, it will, and only throws an error if there's nothing it can do with what you gave it.

The two values you get come out as strings, and the calculations you're performing are done as strings.

So, for subtraction, there is no way to subtract strings, but Javascript will do its best to interpret into something useful anyway. It looks in the strings and sees two numbers, so it interprets the minus as subtracting two numbers, and successfully subtracts them.

"+" is an operator for both addition and string concatenation though, so it puts your numbers together as a string.

To resolve this issue, use `parseInt()` before setting your vars.

```
var number1 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num1").value),
    number2 = parseInt(document.getElementById("num2").value);
```

Answer (score 1):

In JS the "+" sign is a concatenator for strings, values being retrieved from inputs are strings, you need to parse them to integers if you want the "+" to execute addition.

The "-" sign only executes the subtraction operation, so by default it treats numbers as numeric values instead of strings.

Answer (score 1):

This one of the consequences of the JavaScript type coercion rules. The value of an element is always a string, so `number1` and `number2` are both strings. The `+` operator means concatenation when used on strings, so `"3" + "1"` becomes `"31"`. The `-` (minus) operator on the other hand is not defined for strings, it coerces its inputs into numbers. So `"3" - "1"` becomes `3 - 1` which is `2`.

More generally, the operators in JavaScript are only defined for some types. If any other type is used as input, it will first be converted into the expected type. `+` is defined for numbers and for strings, while `-` is only defined for numbers.

Answer (score 1):

The `+` operator can be used as both a string concatenation and an arithmetic operator. Meanwhile, the `-` operator is strictly used in arithmetic operations. Basically if you pass a string into a `+` operation with an integer, JavaScript will first attempt to create a String instead of an integer. The `-` operator stays within the arithmetic scope and does not attempt such casting.

See the [W3C School page on JavaScript operators](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_operators.asp) for more details on the JavaScript operators.

Answer (score 1):

The type number is used so that mobile browsers shows the right keyboards and some browsers use this for validation purposes. Other than this, type=number doesn't parseInt the value typed into it.

This why it concatenates when you do a +.

Answer (score 1):

Since the type of  value  property of a number input field is string when `+` operator is used it will concatenate strings but when `-` operator is used it will treat it as number

```js
function addition() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var number2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  console.log("typeof(number1) > ",typeof(number1))
  console.log("typeof(number1) > ",typeof(number2))
  var total2 = number1 + number2;
  console.log("typeof(total2) > ",typeof(total2))
  document.getElementById("tes4t").innerHTML = total2;
}

function subtract() {
  var number1 = document.getElementById("num1").value;
  var number2 = document.getElementById("num2").value;
  console.log(typeof(number1))
  console.log(typeof(number2))
  var total = number1 - number2;
  console.log("typeof(total) > ",typeof(total))
  document.getElementById("tes4t").innerHTML = total;
}
```

```html
Number1 : <input type="number" id="num1">
<br> Number 2: <input type="number" id="num2">
<br>
<button onclick="addition()">add </button>
<button onclick="subtract()">subtract </button>
<div id="tes4t"></div>
```